# How do I create a DAX expression to display a calculation from a derived table?

Tags: dax

I'm using DaxStudio to test some measures, but am having trouble getting them to work. I can run the following expression, but don't know how to run an average of the field `Mean` to show just the mean of that. I'm basically expecting output to be a single cell with the average.

DAX Query:

```
EVALUATE
    FILTER(
            NATURALINNERJOIN(Alldata, NATURALINNERJOIN('Label', NATURALINNERJOIN('LabelBSkill', 'LabelCSkill'))),
            'LabelCSkill'[Name] = "Critical"
            && 'Label'[Type]="Red"
            )
```

`Mean` is in the table `Alldata` if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
EVALUATE
ROW (
        "Mean", CALCULATE (
            AVERAGE ( Alldata[Mean] ),
            'LabelCSkill'[Name] = "Critical",
            'Label'[Type] = "Red"
        )
)
```